# want to delete only empty folders from directory before last 30 days using batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete only empty folders from directory before last 30 days using `batch`.

I am using following `batch command` to delete empty folders, but I want to delete only those empty folder which modification date is before 30 days.

> for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "c:\filework\system_temp" /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FORFILES command](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can help, by modifying the example from the linked website:

```
rem To list all of the files in the current directory that are at least one year old, type:
forfiles /s /m *.* /d -365 /c "cmd /c echo @file is at least one year old."
```

Afterwards you could check if the directory found is empty: [Check folder is empty using batch command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744981/check-folder-is-empty-using-batch-command)

Comment: Thanks sir, but tried with same logic but i am not getting correct output, it does not delete the empty folders.

Comment: Here is my code, please look on that and suggest me,

Comment: forfiles -p "c:\filework\system_temp" -d -30 -c "cmd /c del /F /Q @path"
forfiles -p "c:\filework\system_temp" -d -30 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /F /Q @path"
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "c:\filework\system_temp" /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"

Comment: @AbhiG What is the problem exactly. Which command returns the unexpected results?